# I am having problems getting my code to output an entire linked list. It is only outputting some of my altered text file instead of the entire thing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am needing help figuring out how to get the rest of the text file to output with the altered GPA and major.  See current output and code.

The Original Student List from Text File:

```
Mickey Mouse 1400 ecology 2.1
Donald Duck 1200 swimming 3.4
Loui Duck 1300 art 2.7
Little Mermaid 1100 Dance 3.9
Goofy Goofball 1500 dumb 1.3
Pluto Dog 1250 running 2.4
Prince Charming 1350 Kinglyness 3
King Arthur 1450 dragons 3.75
Robin Hood 1275 stealing 0.9
Xena Warrior 1325 fighting 4.3
Captain Nemo 1425 fishing 3.3
Captain Kirk 1360 Goofingoff 2.6
Ensign Zulu 1550 Communication 3.7
Peter Parker 1090 swinging 4.75
Wonder Woman 1225 spinning 3.8
Friar Tuck 1150 Religion 2
Richie Rich 1175 beingsnobby 3.6
Bart Simpson 1111 snotty 4.8
```

Changed Student List :

```
Mickey Mouse 1400 Air-Security 2.8
Donald Duck 1200 Biology 4
Loui Duck 1300 Biology 2.8
Little Mermaid 1100 Chemistry 4
Goofy Goofball 1500 Biology 4
Pluto Dog 1250 Pre-Med 2.8
Prince Charming 1350 Air-Security 2.8
King Arthur 1450 Air-Security 2.8
Robin Hood 1275 Chemistry 0.1
Xena Warrior 1325 Biology 0.1
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Student class
class Student
{
public: 
    double Gpa;
    int id;
    string first, last, major;
    Student()
    {   
        first = " ";
        last = " ";
        major = " ";
        id = 0000;
        Gpa = 0;
    }
    Student(string firstName, string lastName, string selectedMajor, int studentID, double studentGPA)
    {
        first = firstName;
        last = lastName;
        major = selectedMajor;
        id = studentID;
        Gpa = studentGPA;
    }

    //Seting New Major for students
    void setMajor(string newMajor)
    {
        major = newMajor;
    }

    //Seting New GPA
    void setGpa(double newGPA)
    {
        Gpa = newGPA;
    }
};

class StudentNode
{
public: 
    StudentNode(){
    }    
    StudentNode(Student s, StudentNode* n)  {       
        student = s;    
        next = n;
    }   
    StudentNode* getNext() {
        return next;
    }    
    Student getStudent(){
        return student;
    }   
    void setNext(StudentNode* n) {  
        next = n;   
    }
private:
    Student student;
    StudentNode *next;
};

//Function Definitions
void add(StudentNode* &head, Student value); 
void print(StudentNode* head);

int main()
{
cout << "The Original Student List from Text File:" << endl;
ifstream in("indata10.txt");
StudentNode* head = NULL;
string majors[5] = {"Engineering", "Biology", "Pre-Med", "Chemistry", "Air-Security"};
string first, last, major;
double gpa[5] = {2.0, 3.5, 2.8, 4.0, 0.1};
double Gpa;
int id, ran1, ran2, integer = 0;
while(!in.eof())
{
    in >> first >> last >> id >> major >> Gpa; //Read in the data for each student
    cout << first << " " << last << " " << id << " " << major << " " << Gpa << endl; //Print the data of the student
    Student student(first, last, major, id, Gpa);
    integer++;
    if (integer <= 10)
    {
        //Altering the Gpa's and Major's using random numbers
        ran1 = rand() % 4 + 1;
        ran2 = rand() % 4 + 1;

        student.setGpa(gpa[ran1]);
        student.setMajor(majors[ran2]);
        add(head, student);
    }

}
print(head);
return 0;
}

//Adding to the linkedlist
void add(StudentNode* &head, Student value) 
{
StudentNode* current = head;    

if (current == NULL) 
{
    head = new StudentNode(value, NULL);    
    return;
}

while (current->getNext() != NULL) 
{
    current = current->getNext();
}
current->setNext(new StudentNode(value, NULL));
}   

//Prints the linked list
void print(StudentNode* head) 
{
StudentNode* current = head;    
cout << "\n Changed Student List :" << endl;
while (current != NULL)  
{
    Student temp = current->getStudent();       
    cout << temp.first << " " << temp.last << " " << temp.id << " " << 
temp.major << " " << temp.Gpa <<  "\t" << endl;
    current = current->getNext();
}
cout << endl;
}
```

I want the entire original text file to be altered and out put under the Changed student list

Answer (score 0):

```
if (integer <= 10)
    {
        //Altering the Gpa's and Major's using random numbers
        ran1 = rand() % 4 + 1;
        ran2 = rand() % 4 + 1;

        student.setGpa(gpa[ran1]);
        student.setMajor(majors[ran2]);
        add(head, student);
    }
```

The above if does not let you add more than 10 elements to your linked list, the rest is good.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you limit the list length to 10 with this if statement?

```
integer++;
if (integer <= 10)
{
  add();
}
```